# PHP array - range key

Tags: php, arrays

I'd like to create an array with some keys will be a range of data.

**Example**:

```php
$data = [
    1 => 1000,
    2 => 500,
    3 => 250,
    4 - 5 => 100,
    6 - 10 => 50,
    11 - 99 => 20
];
```

In this case, `$data[4]` should return 100. `$data[53]` should return 20, etc.

Is this possible without typing everything?

Thanks

Comment: Like a [for](https://www.php.net/manual/en/control-structures.for.php) loop? Or [array_fill()](https://www.php.net/manual/en/function.array-fill.php)?

Comment: You mean I have to create the array via a loop ?

Comment: Not possible. Array keys must match exactly

Comment: Can obtain only through itrating and checking through all the keys. Though it is possible, it wont be an optimised solution

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Using `array_fill()`:

```
<?php

$data = [
   1 => 1000,
   2 => 500,
   3 => 250
   ];

$a = array_fill(4,2, 100);
$b = array_fill(6,5, 50);
$c = array_fill(11,89, 20);

$data = $data + $a + $b + $c;

print_r($data);
```

Answer (score 1):

Naive solution without `array_fill()`. Memory efficient way.

```
<?php

function array_search_key_range(int $needle, array $haystack)
{
    foreach ($haystack as $range => $value) {
        [$min, $max] = array_map('intval', explode('-', (string)$range, 2) + [1 => $range]);
        if ($min <= $needle && $needle <= $max) {
            return $value;
        }
    }

    return false;
}

$data = [
    1 => 1000,
    2 => 500,
    3 => 250,
    '4-5' => 100,
    '6-10' => 50,
    '11-99' => 20,
];

var_dump(array_search_key_range(2, $data)); // 500
var_dump(array_search_key_range(4, $data)); // 100
var_dump(array_search_key_range(10, $data)); // 50
var_dump(array_search_key_range(98, $data)); // 20
var_dump(array_search_key_range(120, $data)); // false
```

Answer (score 0):

Well,
a bit clumsy but you might consider the following:

```php
$data = array_merge([
        0 => null,
        1 => 1000,
        2 => 500,
        3 => 250,
    ],
    array_map(function(){ return 100;}, range(4,5)),
    array_map(function(){ return 50;}, range(6,10)),
    array_map(function(){ return 20;}, range(11,99))
);
```

Answer (score 0):

```
<?php
$data = [
    '1' => 1000,
    '2' => 500,
    '3' => 250,
    '4-5' => 100,
    '6-10' => 50,
    '11-99' => 20];

//Create a new array ($range_arr where you
//create a key for every item in the range specified by your key
//in your $data array
$range_arr = [];
foreach(array_keys($data) as $key) {
    $exploded_key = explode('-', $key);
    $start_range = $exploded_key[0];
    $end_range = $start_range;
    if (isset($exploded_key[1])) {
        $end_range = $exploded_key[1];
    }
    foreach(range($start_range,$end_range) as $nr) {
        $range_arr[$nr] = $data[$key];
    }
}

//for example will output 50
echo $range_arr[7];
```